# Interpolate data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I have a dataframa of the form:

```
t1 x1
t2 NaN
t3 NaN
t4 x4
t5 x5
t6 NaN
t7 x7
```

and so on. I want to interpolate the data in the second column, using the first column. So, the number that would be x2 and x3, I don't want them to be equally spaced between x1 and x4, but to be placed relative to x1 and x4 in the same way that t2 and t3 are placed with respect to t1 and t4. Is there an efficient (without using for loops) way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: X1 X2 is number ?

Comment: @WeNYoBen yes, sorry I forgot to mention.

Comment: are t1 and t2 datetimes?

Comment: @DerekEden They are seconds.

Answer (score 0):

We can do `numpy.interp`

```
s=np.interp(df['col1'].values,
          df.dropna()['col1'].values,
          df.dropna()['col2'].values)
df['col2_new']=s
```

Answer (score 0):

if your times are the index, or if it is acceptable to make them your index, you can achieve this by:

```
df.set_index('col1',inplace=True) #only if they are not already index
df['col2'] = df['col2'].interpolate(method='index')
```

other way would be to make a dummy df, or just use numpy interpolate as other solution shows